# What do "attention problems" mean in this context?

Tags: expressions

I read an abstract from this article:
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16180285

Unfortunately I don't have access to the whole content.

In the end of abstract we read that:

> However, introducing their non-traditional family into their peer group does not seem to interfere with their psychological well-being. Nonetheless, teachers indicate that children from lesbian families experience more **attention problems** compared with children from heterosexual households.

What do *attention problems* mean in this context?

1. Children find it hard to concentrate?
2. Children are in the centre of their peers attention (which might be uncomfortable)?
3. Children ask for teacher's attention too much?

Can we be sure about the selected interpretation?

Comment: Attention-deficit issues.  Your #1. They find it hard to concentrate and to remain on task.

Comment: @TimRomano while that is probably true, it's not clearly possible to eliminate the other two possibilities based on the abstract in the link.

Comment: There's a nice summary of "attention problems" at http://www.pbs.org/wgbh/misunderstoodminds/attentiondiffs.html. Don

Comment: After reading the whole abstract, it is clear to me that the abstract is centered around the potential for children of lesbian DI families to garner unwanted attention from their peers.  So your option 2 is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for your comments and the answer. As the opinions differ, I think that I cannot draw a definite conclusion about a proper interpretation of the abstract. This is also a satisfactory answer for me.

Answer (score 0):

@nuoritoveri, at first I have to eliminate the ***option #2*** from your multiple choice list, because if we presumed that "***attention problems***" may add up to children from lesbian families are in the center of their peers attention. This condition is not aplicable to the children from hetrosexual families, in other words the children from hetrosexual families can not be subjected or be in the center of their peers attention because they are from hetrosexual families. Therefore the comparison, in the light of the statement of the option #2, between these two categories of children, according to the abstract, is not applicable. Although option #3 is a valid option, in my opinion. But I lean more toward option #1 because it is more logical to me that students, in general, may suffer lack of concentration as an ***attention problem*** rather than asking for teachers' attention too much.